# Eclipse: would more CPU cores with HyperThreading help increase speed?

Tags: cpu, eclipse, hyper-threading

I'm programming a very large project in Eclipse. Right now I use a dual core machine with 2GB RAM, but Eclipse is sometimes busy for minutes (refreshing/indexing/building), so I'm upgrading to a new machine (with 16GB RAM and an SSD).

Now I must choose between an Intel 2500K or an Intel 2600K that has HyperThreading.  The price difference is about $100. Would that be worth it, for Eclipse, or is more memory/faster drive much more important for Eclipse ?

Can Eclipse make use of the HyperThreading at all?

Comment: The 2600k only has 4 cores and 8 when hyperthreaded

Comment: The i7 Extreme cpus do have 6 cores, but for an **extreme** price: the i7 3930k is about $600 and 3960x is about $1100

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most programming-related slowdowns (as in slow IDEs) is not due to a CPU-bound condition. It is mostly a harddrive issue (and occasionally memory issue - since you have 2GB of RAM only). You are unlikely to suffer from these slowdowns with a new machine given that you already chose an SSD.

It is unlikely to show any significant difference even if you buy the 2600k. Thus, go for the 2500k (i5).

And for the money, get a bigger SSD (or a dual-SSD setup).